# XeLaTeX: Space between letters

Tags: xetex, fontspec, letterspacing

I use XeLaTeX. I need that words look stretched in some places in the document. How I can configure the space between letters in a word?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on example 44 from the [`fontspec` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fontspec):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=0.0}
USE TRACKING FOR DISPLAY CAPS TEXT

\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=2.0}
USE TRACKING FOR DISPLAY CAPS TEXT
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The documentation remarks:

> This functionality *should not be used for lowercase text*, which is
>   spacing correctly to begin with, but it can be very useful, in small
>   amounts, when setting small caps or all caps titles. Also see the
>   OpenType `Uppercase` option of the `Letters` feature

If you only want to apply the spacing to a few words, enclose it in a group:

```
normal {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=2.0}spaced} normal
```

And you could put it in a macro, of course.