# Add spacing between letters in environment

Tags: spacing, xetex

```
% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title <----
  \sectionlineskip
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

I would like to add some spacing between the letters of the section title. I have tried `{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10.0}\MakeUppercase{\bf #1}}` but this didn't work. What should I do? I am using XelaTex.

I have a lot of trouble finding documentation for stuff like this. Where should I be looking?

I have tried the solution at [XeLaTeX: Space between letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82887/xelatex-space-between-letters?rq=1) but it didn't work.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24917/capital-letter-expanded-letter-space-kerning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you restricted to using XeLaTeX? If you were free to use LuaLaTeX, you could load either the `microtype` package or the `letterspace` package (which is, basically, a much stripped down version of `microtype`). If using LuaLaTeX is feasible, just change

```
\MakeUppercase{\bf #1}
```

to

```
\textls*{\MakeUppercase{\bfseries #1}}
```

(Aside: `\bf` is deprecated for LaTeX documents. Use either `{\bfseries ...}` or `\textbf{...}`.)

See section 7 of the user guide of the `microtype` package for more information on `\textls` and how to change the amount of letterspacing (aka tracking).

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `\addfontfeatures` on a font that has not been explicitly loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\NewDocumentCommand{\spaceduppercase}{m}{%
  {\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=10}\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\spaceduppercase{Test} TEST

\textbf{\spaceduppercase{Test}} \textbf{TEST}

\end{document}
```

So change your (wrong) `\MakeUppercase{\bf #1}` into

```
\textbf{\spaceduppercase{#1}}
```