# Highlighting a name by increasing the spacing as in books of the 19th century

Tags: spacing, typography

In books from the 19th century and the first half of the 20th century, I realised, that sometimes names are highlighted by increasing the spacing inside these words.

Here an Example from G. Frege's "Begriffsschrift"
[image]

where the name "Leibniz" is highlighted in this particular way. Is there a name for this style of typesetting? How can it be achieved in LaTeX?

I am interested in a solution for all flavours of LaTeX but a solution which is compatible with XeTeX and fontspec would be the preferred one.

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82887/xelatex-space-between-letters specifically for XeLaTeX.

Comment: In addition to @Marijn 's links, to answer your question of whether there's a name for this, it's called *Sperrsatz* in German (which I presume you might have knowledge of since you're quoting from a German language text).

Comment: @Marijn I was able to use the answers to these questions to write a command which does what I want but I am not sure whether this is an exact duplicate.

Comment: If it's a near duplicate (very similar question, main component of solution the same) then it also qualifies as a duplicate. If you think your new command is an improvement or useful extension of the answers to the other questions then you can consider posting a separate answer there. If your current question is closed as a duplicate then new visitors following the duplicate can benefit from your solution.

Comment: @Marijn I am fine with marking it as duplicate. My solution should be obvious for everyone with a basic knowledge of "\newcommand" so I guess it does not really add value.